# How to make a tableview divided into sections by letter like the contacts app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to replicate the contacts table view in my app. So I have a list of contacts displayed in a table view however I would like the table view to be sectioned into all the letters of the alphabet and the names of the contacts to be placed in the section related to the lister letter of their first name. Like this

[image]

How do I get that view? So far this is all I have done.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [displayNames count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";

    /*ContactCell *cell = (ContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }*/
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
     //   cell.name.text = [displayNames
       //                        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *namer = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    namer.text=[displayNames
                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    /*
     Get the picture urls from the picture array and then 
     I loop through the array and initialize all the urls with 
     a NSUrl and place the loaded urls in anouther nsmutable array
     */
    urls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (id object in pictures) {
        //NSDictionary *names = res[@"image"];
        NSString *name = object;
        NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:name];
        [urls addObject:url];
    }
   // cell.profile.image= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    UIImageView *profiler = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    profiler.image= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the index on the right side too, or just sections for the letters of the alphabet? Also, what does your data source look like? Do you have a simple array, an array of dictionaries, something else?

Comment: I would like the index on the right too. I'm filling the list with an array of names.

Comment: Is your list currently just a simple array of names?

Comment: The table view cells have a name and a picture for each person. So I have one array that initializes all the names and another array that initializes all the pictures.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample apps referenced in the docs for `UITableView`. At least one (if not more) of the samples show you how to create such a table.

Comment: I checked a few of them but it just taught me how to build simple tableviews or tableviews with prototype cells, nothing like the contact table view. Anyway if you have a link, that would be great.

Comment: Look at the TableViewSuite sample. It has 5 smaller projects. One or more of those does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy solution using the 3rd party [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) data model class [`TLIndexPathDataModel`](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html). It is specifically designed for working with index paths and sections, so you can accomplish what you need with minimal complexity. And here is a [full, working demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2183704/Contacts%20Demo.zip).

First define a class to represent a contact. This gives you a place to define `firstName`, `lastName`, `displayName` and `sectionName`:

```
@interface Contact : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *displayName;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *sectionName;
- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName;
@end
```

The `sectionName` property just returns the first character of the `firstName`. Then if your table view subclasses `TLTableViewController`, the implementation would look something like this:

```
@implementation ContactsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

    //get actual list of contacts here...
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"John" lastName:@"Doe"]];
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Sally" lastName:@"Smith"]];
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Bob" lastName:@"Marley"]];
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Tim" lastName:@"Cook"]];
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Jony" lastName:@"Ives"]];
    [contacts addObject:[[Contact alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Henry" lastName:@"Ford"]];

    //sort by section name
    [contacts sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:YES]]];

    //set the data model
    self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:contacts sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" identifierKeyPath:nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //get contact for index path from data model and configure cell
    Contact *contact = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = contact.displayName;

    return cell;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.indexPathController.dataModel.sectionNames;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return index;
}

@end
```

The key thing is that `TLIndexPathDataModel` automatically organizes your data into sections using the `sectionNameKeyPath` set to @"sectionName". Then in your view controller logic, you can easily access the contact for a given index path by calling:

```
Contact *contact = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**update**

You'd actually want to do a second-level sort on display name:

```
[contacts sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES]]];
```

**update #2**

There is a new block-based initializer for `TLIndexPathDataModel` that makes this a lot easier if you don't want to define a custom data object just to add a `sectionNameKeyPath` property. For example, one can use the new initializer to organize a list of strings as illustrated in the ["Blocks" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Blocks/Blocks/BlocksTableViewController.m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *items = [@[
           @"Fredricksburg",
           @"Jelly Bean",
           ...
           @"Metadata",
           @"Fundamental",
           @"Cellar Door"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    //generate section names by taking the first letter of each item
    self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:items
                                                                    sectionNameBlock:^NSString *(id item) {
        return [((NSString *)item) substringToIndex:1];
    } identifierBlock:nil];
}
```

Comment: ... and then @MichaelNana was never seen again.

Comment: Maybe he's just too embarrassed to come back here and report as he promised? The mystery thickens. Anyway, for me the tip looking at the "TableViewSuite sample" helped.